# How to backup File system

Tags: linux, debian

I used sudo rm -r /etc/apt and my apt folder in file system got deleted because of which i am not able even to use Internet in terminal also.can any body suggest me how to back up my apt folder in file system

Answer (score 3):

Little late to run backups now. Generally you should be backing up your important data *before* you destroy it.

I would suggest, in the following order:

- reinstall
- copy /etc/apt from an identically-configured machine
- `debootstrap` a debian install into a directory somewhere, install the necessary packages (check your package manager log for clues), then copy back /etc/apt

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused as to why you would be unable to use the Internet in your terminal - /etc/apt/ (essentially) only governs how you retrieve new Debian packages.
Can you still do a 'ping www.google.com' from the command line? If that does not work, you have issues that go beyond a lost /etc/apt/

You should be able to recreate a working /etc/apt relatively easily - the only thing that you can't live without is /etc/apt/sources.list. 
There are also two directories that apt requires, but they can be empty.

Try the following:

```
mkdir -p /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
echo 'deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the last line, change 'stable' to whatever you are using, and add 'non-free' and/or 'contrib' at the end of the line, if needed.

Then do an `apt-get update`, and you should be back in business.

You'll still have to add any extra repositories you had in your sources.list, and and `deb-src` line corresponding to the  `deb` line, but the basics should be covered.

Good luck!